# Не могу добавить зависимости Maven при запуске проекта

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день! Решил запустить проект на новой машине с Ubuntu, при его переносе зависимости установились сами, кроме этих двух. Пробовал установить вручную, скачивал с сайта MSoft, устанавливал через команду mvn install, результата нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

Comment: как устанавливали руками?

Comment: mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc42.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc42 -Dversion=4.2 -Dpackaging=jar

Comment: Проблема решена. Удалось добавить зависимость, распаковав архив в папку с локальным репозиторием maven .m2/repository... и произведя установку по команде выше. Возможно проблема еще была в том, что проект надо было закрыть и открыть заново, чтобы ошибка исчезла.

Comment: не обязательно переоткрывать - нужно было реимпорт сделать - 1я кнопка на панели справа

Comment: Пробовал, не помогало

Comment: Установил аналогично зависимость библиотеки jasperreports-extensions. mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jasperreports-extensions-3.5.3.jar -DgroupId=jasperreports -DartifactId=jasperreports-extensions -Dversion=3.5.3 -Dpackaging=jar